# Php add assoc array key if not exits?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a function which populates an array for a Google Chart. But sometimes a specific value doesn't exists and I have a array key to short

This is what i want to have

```
Array
(
    [P] => 72
    [U] => 1
    [X] => 0
    [w] => 0
)
```

P, U, X and W are values from another assoc array with keyname "code"

Php function problem, if the key value doesn't exists it doesn't come into the  array

```
function convertJS($inputArray) {
// $lookup = ['P','U','X','W'];
  foreach ($inputArray as $key => $value) {
    $tmp[$value['code']] += 1;
  }
/*
  if (in_array($value['code'], $lookup)) {
    $tmp[$value['code']] += 1;
  } else {

  }
*/
  return $tmp;
}
```

And this is what I got:

```
Array
(
   [P] => 72
   [U] => 1
)
```

So how do I make sure every key (P,U,X,W) has a value?

Comment: Build an array with all the keys you want with a default value and use `array_merge`

Comment: try insert `$tmp = ['P'=>0, 'U'=>0, 'X'=>0, 'W'=>0]` before foreach

Comment: ... and use array_count_values instead of writing your own count routine for that. PHP has a lot of stuff in array treating department. )

Comment: To me it is not clear what you want to do. What result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to fill the array with specific keys and default values, you have to specify those first. You can use `array_fill_keys` for that. (Provided by @raina77ow)

```
$defaultKeys = ['P', 'U', 'X', 'W'];

$default = array_fill_keys($defaultKeys, 0);
```

Your `convertJS` function only counts toe occurances of the `code` field in the inner arrays, you can use `array_column` to extract the values of `code` for later analysis.

```
$codes = array_column($inputArray, 'code');
```

This will create an array like:

```
['P', 'U', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'U', 'P', 'P'];
```

Afterwards you can count them with `array_count_values` to count the occurances of the `code` entries.

```
$occurances = array_count_values($codes);
```

This will create an array like:

```
[
    'P' => 72
    'U' => 7
];
```

At last you only have to merge it into the defaul counts with `array_merge`:

```
return array_merge($default, $occurances);
```

Combined:

```
function convertJS($inputArray) {
    $defaultKeys = ['P', 'U', 'X', 'W'];
    $default = array_fill_keys($defaultKeys, 0);
    $codes = array_column($inputArray, 'code');
    $occurances = array_count_values($codes);
    return array_merge($default, $occurances);
}
```

Comment: This one I really can follow, the other solution is also a good one. But I am not good with all the built-in array function and nested array function doesn't make it easier to read back.
One more question, do you know of a vid link/tutorial where 80% of the PHP array function are covered/??

Comment: One followup question how can i change the chars to words ` $tmpArr =  array_merge($lookup, $occurances);
            // Replace With Words
$tmpArr = array_merge($default, $occurances);
            $wordsArray = ['Pilot','Union','Xerox','Ex'];
            $return = array_replace($tmpArr, $wordsArray);` and I also tried `$return = str_replace($lookupKeys, $wordsArray, $tmpArr);`

Answer (score 1):

Don't write your own code for the tasks already solved, use <del>the force, Luke</del> array helper functions instead:

```
$inputArray = [
  ['code' => 'P'], 
  ['code' => 'P'], 
  ['code' => 'U'], 
  ['code' => 'U']
];
$chars  = ['P', 'U', 'X', 'W'];
$result = array_merge(
  array_fill_keys($chars, 0),
  array_count_values(array_column($inputArray, 'code'))
);
var_dump($result);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/934232).

Explanation:

- [**array_fill_keys()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php) creates a 'default count array', with all supplied characters as keys and `0` as their default value
- [**array_column()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) takes one array and retrieves values of each element' specific property (`code` in this case) as another array
- [**array_count_values()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)... well, counts the values in supplied array
- [**array_merge**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) just merges those arrays, using count results for keys have those defined and 0 (of default value) for the rest.

Comment: Hm. now you get all values presented in array and such result can be obtained by using just array_count_values. If your plan was to obtain counts only for chars presented in the 1st array you need array_intersect_keys instead og merge. It's a bad answer

Comment: @splash58 OP clearly stated, that he has a superlist of codes and that the codes in the `$inputArray` are just a part list of those. Using `array_merge` is therefore a correct answer. The only incorrect part here is `array_count_values($inputArray)`, because `$inputArray` is a multidimensional array while `array_count_values` only works for unidimensional string or int arrays. Yet that part of the answer is not part of the question.

Comment: where is *$inputArray is a multidimensional array* in your demo? It will be interested to see your solution working in that case

Comment: You get test data when set of chars in inputArray is less than one in chars. It's not always . What's     about $inputArray = [ 'P', 'P'  'A']; ?

Comment: @splash58 You're right, I missed that 'code' part; should count values of `array_column()` result instead. Fixed that in my answer. As for your last comment, could you explain it a bit?

Comment: I did not understand from the question that $inputArray can't to contain another values than in  $chars? But there is no info in contra :)

Comment: @raina77ow tx for your answer although I opted for the other answer as the way you are using the nested arrays (which is efficient) makes me read the code 3x times ;). This one I really can follow, the other solution is also a good one. I do have one more question, do you know of a vid link/tutorial where 80% of the built PHP array function are covered/??

Comment: @user9191816 Sure, that's ok. As for tutorial, you don't have to remember the functions' signature - just check for them when you need them. )